# Find the relationship between $x$ and $y$ so that $y:=0\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}\Leftrightarrow x:=y\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration, functions, terminology, alternative-proof, substitution

> Find the relationship between $x$ and $y$ so that
> $$y:=0\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}\Leftrightarrow x:=y\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I'm having trouble solving the multivariable calculus if I change the order between ${\rm d}x, {\rm d}y,$ so I try a new approach like finding function $y=\!f_{1}\left ( x \right )$ and $x=\!f_{2}\left ( y \right )$ but unsuccessfully . I need to the help

Comment: What are the limits for your integral? $y \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0 \leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$? Now you want to change order $dx \ dy$ to $dy \ dx$? Is that the question?

Comment: Yes, but I wanna try a different approach..

Comment: ok I see it now

Comment: Thanks a rl lot

Comment: I think to get the answer you must have to provide more details. Such as what is the main problem ? You told about a double integral, what is it ? Because it seems incomplete question from my side.@hd_30102

Comment: I fixed smthang

Comment: Your previous edit does not provide any extra information ? We need detailed information about your question.

Comment: @nmasanta sorry

Comment: @haidangel I think you need to give more details. For the example by Martund's answer, do you mean you can evaluate the double integral by a new approach? In your new approach, you need to find two functions $f_1, f_2$ such that $y= f_{1}\left ( x \right ), x= f_{2}\left ( y \right )$?

Comment: Yes, kind of it

Comment: @haidangel You should use @, otherwise I can not receive notification. Do you have example about your new approach?

Comment: No such an idea

Comment: @RiverLi, I'm having trouble solving double integral without graphing.

Comment: @haidangel Why without graphing? We often need graphing of the region to calculate the iterated integral?

Comment: @RiverLi, it's just for my curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give an example of an integral such that changing order of the integration changes limits like you've said in the title of your question. Consider the following double integral:
\begin{equation}
\iint\limits_{0<x<y<\frac\pi2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
\end{equation}
That, which I've written below the integral sign is the region of integration, and this integration will find out area of the region given by
\begin{equation}
A = \left\{(x,y)\Bigg|0<x<y<\frac\pi2\right\}
\end{equation}
in the plane.

Separating the limits, and doing integration in this order, we get the required integral to be
\begin{align}
I&=\iint\limits_A\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_0^\frac\pi2\int_0^y\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_0^\frac\pi2y\mathrm dy\\
&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align}

Changing the order of integration, we get,
\begin{align}
I&=\iint\limits_A\mathrm dy\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^\frac\pi2\int_x^\frac\pi2\mathrm dy\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^\frac\pi2\left(\dfrac\pi2-x\right)\mathrm dx\\
&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align}

Since the problem is not entirely clear to me, please comment if it doesn't answer your question.